# SQL query to exclude all records that have that have been assigned to a group and or more these record have certain value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to retrieve all records that have been grouped together and of these records, I need to return all record if none of them has VP under party_type.

so basically if records are grouped together and one of them is equal to VP under party type then I should exclude all associated grouped with a record that has party type = VP

```
CLUSTER_ID  PARTY_NAME                                      PARTY_TYPE
35          Yorken cc                                       V  
35          Yorken cc                                       V  
35          Yorken Zim                                      V  
35          Yorken                                          V  
243         Vulcan Catering Equipment Pty Ltd               VP
243         Vulcan Catering Equipment Pty Ltd               V
243         Vulcan Catering Equipment (Pty) Ltd             V
```

results should return all records grouped under cluster_id 35 because none of the records has VP

Comment: Please check whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server. You have tagged both. Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from tablename  a
    where a.CLUSTER_ID not in  (select b.CLUSTER_ID from tablename  b WHERE party_type='VP')

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
    where not exists (select 1 from tablename b on a.cluster_id=b.cluster_id and party_type='VP')
```